# T SQL select last sale of each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve the last sale date for each customer as follows but it is just returning the last entry in the table:

```
Select top 1 InvoiceDate
,Customer
from salestable a
order by InvoiceDate desc
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server (presumably, it could be Sybase I suppose)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `TOP 1` - that's why you're returning only 1 result.

Try using `MAX` and `GroupBy` Customer

```
SELECT Customer, MAX(InvoiceDate)
FROM SalesTable
GROUP By Customer
ORDER By MAX(InvoiceDate) DESC
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I had it like that the first time.  First it's giving an error that InvoiceDate should be in the Group by, then I add it in the group by and its returning the same customer with different InvoiceDates

Comment: @wilest - you need MAX(InvocieDate) in the ORDER By that's why. I've updated my answer.